How to blow insulation into a curved wall
I have been planning a project to improve the comfort in my condo by blowing insulation into the walls and ceiling crawl space. But some of my exterior walls have curved bay windows, and it occurred to me that I'm not sure how to go about repairing this sort of wall after putting a hole in it. I don't think I can just drop in a patch of drywall and slap some mud on it.
Is blowing insulation into a wall like this a DIY project, and if so, how would I go about it?


start by determining the location of all of the studs
